# Sequelize, Nested Findall and merge all find all result

Tags: sequelize.js, findall

This is the requirement code, dataJoin (array of  Objects like multiple records) result, have json values. These json values, have to find the related items. So that, used for statement, for find the json values. Collection json values, using the userService function, and get the data, then these data merged to parent data. It's not working. Because, before complete the for loop statement, the res.send ("...") item has executed, this is my problem...

Please any one guide me...

Thanks

```
  table1Obj
  .findAll(
    {  
      include: [
        {
            model: assocaitonTableObject,
            required: false,
        }
      ],
      where: req.query,
    })
    .then((dataJoin) => {


      for(element of dataJoin ) {
        const arrayCollection = [];
        let whereConstraint = {};
        JSON.parse(element.joinedUsersList).forEach( async (ele) => { 
          arrayCollection.push(ele.userId);
        });;
        whereConstraint = {
          id : {
            [Op.in]: arrayCollection
          }
        }
        const usesrListData = userService.customfindAll(whereConstraint);
        element.userListData = usesrListData;
      }

      res.send({
        status:200,
        message:"OK",
        data:dataJoin
      });

    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        status:500,
        message:
          err.message ,
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that your `userService.customfindAll` returns an Promise, then you should await for it. If is not, check if you awaited for every Promise.

My second guess it that you should'nt pass an async function for `array.forEach`, try use `for`instead. I'm not sure if this will help, but you can try.

Comment: are you really awaiting for everythink? Your problem looks like some Promise is not been awaited. I know this is reduntant, but check it. PS: post your userService and customFindAll code.

Comment: Alex, Can you share me your email please